# Escaping JSON Payload with back slash

Tags: json, mule

I have an external service that returns a JSON Payload as below

```
{
    "GetIPAResult": "{\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Pan1\",\"Email\":\"abc@example.com\"},{\"Name\":\"Pan2\",\"Email\":\"xyz@example.com\"}]}"
}
```

How could I escape the back slash? I need to use a json path and currently I cant do it. Is there a better way than String Replace? Thanks.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

Just simply parse your JSON string. like that.

```
var response = {
    "GetIPAResult": "{\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Pan1\",\"Email\":\"abc@example.com\"},{\"Name\":\"Pan2\",\"Email\":\"xyz@example.com\"}]}"
};

var result = $.parseJSON(response.GetIPAResult);
```

Now you can get your data (in result variable) without back slash.

Comment: Thanks Sohel. We are using Mule and mule uses Rhinoscript. Neverthless I plugged this in but getting an error as below Exception stack is:
1. SyntaxError: Unexpected token: u (<Unknown Source>#5) (sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError)
  sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime:3770 (null)

Answer (score 0):

hari .. at a moment your json structure are as follows

> {"key": "value"}

where value is a stringify of {"Data" : JSONARRAY}

here 2 case arise..

**case 1:**
 try to change the structure of return json to

> {"key": JSONOBJECT}
>   where JSONOBJECT -> {"DATA": JSONARRAY}

**case 2:**

try to convert return json to

> {"key": JSONOBJECT}
>   where JSONOBJECT -> {"DATA": JSONARRAY}

by replace **"{** with **{** , **\"** with **"** and **}"** with **}**

hence the result of

```
{
"GetIPAResult": "{\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Pan1\",\"Email\":\"abc@example.com\"},{\"Name\":\"Pan2\",\"Email\":\"xyz@example.com\"}]}"
}
```

to

```
{
"GetIPAResult": {"Data":[{"Name":"Pan1","Email":"abc@example.com"},{"Name":"Pan2","Email":"xyz@example.com"}]}
 }
```